# Rails 3 route scope, exclude one action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my routes set up as

```
scope "/admin" do
    resources :profiles
end
```

So I am getting the expected routes with /admin/profiles.  I want to exclude the show action from having this prefix. Is there an easy way to do this? Every solution I saw in the docs was around nested resources, I'm sure I overlooked something though. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think

```
scope "/admin", do
  resources :profiles, except: :show
end
```

is what you need.

see more at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created